# Selection box insert multiple times in database

Tags: php, sql, loops, pdo, mysqli

This is what the page looks like:

[image: What the current page looks like]

And this is what the database looks like:

[image: Database]

Now, I had this all working with textfields. (When you press save, the text fields get inserted in the `bogie_nr`.
Now, I don't want to have text fields but checkboxes.
So, if I select the first 2 checkboxes, and press save. I want the database to insert the number `1` by the `axle_nr` 1 and 2.
Now, I want the first 2 boxes to be disabled (So you can't check them again).

Now when you select the 3rd and 4th box, and press save. I want the database to insert the number `2` by the 3rd and 4th `axle_nr`.

When everything is filled in, I want a button that redirects me to a new page.
How do I do this?

Code (for the checkboxes only):

```
<tr>
    <?php   
        $show_axle = $database->bogies($_GET['train_id']);
        foreach($show_axle as $bogiebox){ ?>
            <input type='hidden' name='bogie_id[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>'>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' placeholder = "enter bogie number">
            </td>
    <?php
        } 
    ?>
</tr>
```

Function:

```
function bogies($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM bogie WHERE train_id = :id2";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id2", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Behind my save button is right now a page: `end_result.php` . Right there I have a function:

```
function update_bogie($id) {
        $sql = "UPDATE bogie SET bogie_nr = :bogie_nr WHERE bogie_id = :bogie_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':bogie_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(":bogie_nr", $_POST['bogie_nr'][$id], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
    }
```

This updates the bogie table (Works when I change the checkboxes to textfields)

What i want now:
Checkboxes. When I check the first 2 boxes, and press save. I want the number 1 to be inserted 2 times for axle 1 and 2 in the database.
After that, I want the first 2 boxes to be disabled selected. So you can't select them once again.

**EDIT:**

What the ids look like:
[image]

***THE ALMOST WORKING EDIT:***

Okay, so the checkboxes now insert in the database. Also they are disabled when they are inserted in the database.Only a few problems now:

1. When i insert them for the first time. The value = 1.   But on the
   2nd insert it also is 1. while it should be 2.
2. I need to refresh the page in order to see wich select boxes are
   disabled. I want this to happen immediately.
3. When i insert new values. the old (Disabled one) go back to `NULL`. But it             should keep the old value.

Code i have now:

```
<form method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" value="true" id="y" name="y">
    <div id="axle_bogie_border">
        <div id="train_adjusted">
            <h2>
                Train
            </h2>
        </div>
        <table id="distance_margin">
            <div id="bogiebox">
                <tr> 
                    <?php    
                        $x = 1;  
                        foreach($show_axle as $bogiebox){ ?>
                        <input type='hidden' name='bogie_id[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>'>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                if($bogiebox['bogie_nr'] == ''){
                            ?>
                                <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" value="<?= $x ?>" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' placeholder = "enter bogie number"></td>
                            <?php
                                }
                                else{ 
                            ?>
                                <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" checked disabled value="<?= $x ?>" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' placeholder = "enter bogie number"></td><?php } }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' id="add_train_button1" value='Save'>

        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['y'])){
            $validbogies = false;
                    //validate
                    if(($_POST['bogie_id']) >0){
                            if($_POST['bogie_id'] >0){
                                    $validbogies = true;
                            }elseif($_POST['bogie_id'] <= 0){
                                echo "Error!";
                            }
                            else{
                                    echo "Error!." . "<br>";
                            }
                    }else{
                            echo "Error!" . "<br>";
                    }

                    //If valid, then insert.
                    if($validbogies){
                        foreach($_POST['bogie_id'] as $id) {
                            $update_axle = $database->update_bogie($id);
                        }
                            $x++;
                            unset($_POST['y']);  
                            echo "Yea! Things have been moved to the database :)";

                    }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the function is still the same as the old one.

***EDIT***:
Here a example:

[image: example]

Comment: do these checkboxes always have bogie_id 455-458 or does it vary?

Comment: They vary. When i add a new train, with 8 axles. they will be 459-466

Comment: you do know which train is currently being viewed? you have saved somewhere in php or javascript that you are currently viewing train 117?

Comment: When i first insert my train, i ask for the last inserted train_id. Also it is in this function: ($_GET['train_id']).

Comment: is this all the code you have? cause the things you are asking are more than what you provided code-wise, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is the code for the checkboxes wich is all you need, since it is already selecting the good train_id Etc. It was working before with textfields, but i want/need to use checkboxes. I tried putting it in a while loop. but it did not give me the results i wanted. Also i dont know how i should disable the filled in checkboxes.

Comment: when you are echoing your checkboxes, check if the record in the database it belongs to has a value for bogie_nr and if it does set the attributes for the <input type=checkbox/> , the attributes are: checked and disabled you need these 2 if you wish for your checkbox to look checked and not be able to edit it

Comment: like this: <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" ... etc ... "enter bogie number" checked disabled>

Comment: If you provide me with the code behind your save button I might be able to help you with the other part to

Comment: The code behind the save button is based on the old version (with text fields) il edit how it looks

Comment: so what is being saved now when you click save?

Comment: The row "bogie_nr" stays empty because the boxes have no value.

Comment: have you tried giving your checkboxes a value attribute?

Comment: I can do that, but when i for example let's say: give them the value axle_nr. they go from 1-x . but axle 2 should not have a value of 2. because it might be 1. and axle 4 should not have the value 4. becuase it might be 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
        $show_axle = $database->bogies($_GET['train_id']);

        // First question : When everything is filled in, 
        // i want a button that redirects me to a new page.

        if(count($show_axle) == 4)
           echo "<button type=\"button\" onClick=location.href=''>Click Me!</button>";

          // Second question :
         // WE display the missing checkboxes
        // We will display until we found the first value axle_nr
       // (i.e. the checkbox the user click last time)
      //  when we found we need to move to the next value of axle_nr
        else
        {
            $j = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i)
            {
                 if($show_axle[$j]['axle_nr'] != ($i + 1))
                 {
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='bogie_id[" . 
                          $bogiebox['bogie_id']. "]' value='" .  
                          $bogiebox['bogie_id'] . "'><td>";

                    echo "<input type='checkbox' id='bogie_axle_fields' 
                            name='bogie_nr[" . $bogiebox['bogie_id'] . 
                            "]' placeholder='enter bogie number'></td>";

                 }
                 else
                   ++$j;
           }
?>
```

That should do it (mb some mistakes on echo but algorithm is ok).

Comment: this doesn't help in saving the values in database though, this is solely for showing the button, but the problem here is that it also won't make the checkboxes unclickable

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind your save button try this: (I am assuming the id's for your checkboxes are like this: bogie_nr[455]

```
    function update_bogie($id) {
            $sql = "UPDATE bogie SET bogie_nr = :bogie_nr WHERE bogie_id = :bogie_id";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':bogie_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if(isset($_POST['bogie_nr' . '[' . $id .']' ]){
              $sth->bindParam(":bogie_nr", $_POST['bogie_nr' . '[' . $id .']' ], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            else {
              $sth->bindParam(":bogie_nr", 'NULL', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            $sth->execute();
    }
```

EDIT FOR CORRECT NUMBER:
Mitch to get your number try doing a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bogie
WHERE train_id = @youridhere;
```

This will return you the amount of bogies you already have for that train, just do +1 or +2 depending on how many elements you are adding (use a counter in your for loop) and you have your correct number to insert

Comment: This should at least give you some kind of data in your database I think

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference. On this line: $sth->bindParam(":bogie_nr", NULL, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: to start off, we don't actually want to come into that else statement, that means it didn't find your checkbox, what does the name of your checkbox look like?

Comment: I mean what does your html element look like at runtime: this one:
name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]

Comment: Like that, what i just edited? but then only checked. <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' placeholder = "enter bogie number">

Comment: so your php tag doesn't actually work? it's not echoing a number? so basically there is no difference between the first checkbox and the second etc...

Comment: Edited the code, should work now to insert something into database when you check the checkbox, woops changed wrong values, should be ok now

Comment: try 
$sth->bindParam(":bogie_nr", 'NULL', PDO::PARAM_STR,4);

Comment: strange, I'm sorry man but that is as far as my knowledge goes, I have 15 more minutes before I have to go offline so I can't really help you anymore, I hope someone will be able to help you today, if not try setting up a http://phpfiddle.org/ that I could play around with tomorrow

Comment: But @Jeremy C. I want all the axles to have a value 1. But after i selected and send 2, i want all the values to change to 2. so the next send will send the value 2 for the selected boxes. Thats why i do $x++ after the insert.

Comment: then try something like (not sure if you mean axle_nr or bogie_nr so I just took axle): SELECT MAX(axle_nr) FROM table WHERE train_id=@yourid --- This will get the highest axle_nr for that train, just add +1 and you have your axle number for the new bogies :D

Comment: Made an edit with a hopefully clear example. @Jeremy C.

Comment: Use the same thing I did in my previous comment but replace axle_nr by bogie_nr